# Rebuilding a partially failed RAID5 array

Tags: debian, mdadm, readynas

Last week we had a series of power failures, which unfortunately lead to HDD4 dying in our ReadyNAS drive. The hard disk was swapped out, and the ReadyNAS automatically started rebuilding the array, stating it would take 2 hours to complete.

However, after approximately 47 minutes, HDD3 appears to have failed. The ReadyNAS then reported that the array was in a degraded state due to the failure of 3, and I received errors stating the volumes were no longer available.

I was able to SSH into the server, and using `mdadm --force` it is now up and running, however, is still showing that only 12&4 are used in the array. 3 is still showing healthy.

There appear to be 3 partitions, which are then added to a RAID5 array. /dev/sdc is included in two of them, but not the third:

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
    Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Feb 20 14:19:18 2014
  Raid Level : raid1
  Array Size : 4193268 (4.00 GiB 4.29 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 4193268 (4.00 GiB 4.29 GB)
  Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
  Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Update Time : Tue Nov  1 16:11:41 2016
      State : clean
Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0

       Name : 30469A7FFABC:0
       UUID : 386349a8:baa621d2:4d938e5e:3aba33db
     Events : 7417

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
   1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
   2       8       33        2      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   4       8       49        3      active sync   /dev/sdd1

 mdadm --detail /dev/md1
 /dev/md1:
    Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Feb 20 14:19:18 2014
  Raid Level : raid6
  Array Size : 1048448 (1024.05 MiB 1073.61 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 524224 (512.02 MiB 536.81 MB)
  Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
  Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Update Time : Sun Oct 30 21:47:42 2016
      State : clean
  Active Devices : 4
  Working Devices : 4
  Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

     Layout : left-symmetric
 Chunk Size : 64K

       Name : 30469A7FFABC:1
       UUID : 8ec1d475:bc4293be:63b1e929:a1669431
     Events : 77

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8        2        0      active sync   /dev/sda2
   1       8       18        1      active sync   /dev/sdb2
   2       8       34        2      active sync   /dev/sdc2
   4       8       50        3      active sync   /dev/sdd2



 mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
    Version : 1.2
 Creation Time : Thu Feb 20 14:19:18 2014
 Raid Level : raid5
 Array Size : 2916122112 (2781.03 GiB 2986.11 GB)
 Used Dev Size : 972040704 (927.01 GiB 995.37 GB)
 Raid Devices : 4
 Total Devices : 3
 Persistence : Superblock is persistent

 Update Time : Tue Nov  1 16:09:21 2016
      State : active, degraded

Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0

     Layout : left-symmetric
 Chunk Size : 64K

       Name : 30469A7FFABC:2
       UUID : 59f98978:f215b5ec:2e2d93b5:19f17e1f
     Events : 9559

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
   1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
   2       0        0        2      removed
   4       8       51        3      active sync   /dev/sdd3
```

As you can see, /dev/sdc3 is missing from the main data array.

I have tried to add it, but it will not do so - it tries to add it as a 5th disk.

I've tried to remove it from the array:

```
 mdadm --remove /dev/md2 /dev/sdc3
 mdadm: hot remove failed for /dev/sdc3: No such device or address
```

Any suggestions on how I can re-add /dev/sdc3?

Comment: `mdadm -a /dev/md2 /dev/sdc3`

Comment: This fails: `mdadm: add new device failed for /dev/sdc3 as 5: Invalid argument`